# Массив в реактивных формах. Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5, angular, formbuilder

Хочу вывести форму, в которой одно поле - массив, и для каждого елемента массива мне нужно вывести свои инпуты.

Компонент:

```
userData.contacts = [ 
{contact_type: "phone", value: "380666666666"},
{contact_type: "email", value: "ggg@gg.gg"},   
{contact_type: "website", value: "www.good.co"}
];

this.contactInfoForm = new FormGroup({
          contacts: this.fb.array( userData.contacts )
        });
```

HTML:

```
 <form [formGroup]="contactInfoForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit('contactInfoForm')">
<div formArrayName="contacts" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls; let i = index;">
              <div formGroupName="i">
                <label>{{ contact.value.contact_type }}</label>
                <input formControlName="value">
              </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

если вывести в консоле форму то там объект с кучей данных.

```
   asyncValidator: null
controls:
contacts: FormArray
asyncValidator: null
controls: Array(3)
0: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, …}
1: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, …}
2: FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
dirty: (...)
disabled: (...)
enabled: (...)
errors: null
invalid: (...)
length: (...)
parent: (...)
pending: (...)
pristine: true
root: (...)
status: "DISABLED"
statusChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
touched: false
untouched: (...)
updateOn: (...)
valid: (...)
validator: null
value: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
valueChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
_onCollectionChange: ƒ ()
_onDisabledChange: []
_parent: FormGroup {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, …}
__proto__: AbstractControl
__proto__: Object
dirty: (...)
disabled: (...)
enabled: (...)
errors: null
invalid: (...)
parent: (...)
pending: (...)
pristine: true
root: (...)
status: "DISABLED"
statusChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
touched: false
untouched: (...)
updateOn: (...)
valid: (...)
validator: null
value: {contacts: Array(3)}
valueChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
_onCollectionChange: ƒ ()
_onDisabledChange: []
__proto__: AbstractControl
```

Я по разному уже пытался выводить инфу. Никак не получается. Даже если тупо копи-паст куски с примеров в интеренете. Те же проблемы. Те же ошибки.

Ошибка:

```
Cannot find control with path: 'contacts -> 0 -> value'
```

Попробовал так:

```
<input [formControlName]="contact.value.value">
```

получаю ошибку:

```
'contacts -> 0 -> 380666666666'
```

Comment: А что за проблемы? Что за ошибки? Добавьте информацию об этом в вопрос.

Comment: спс. добавил) забыл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormBuilder.prototype.array` первым аргументом ждет не массив данных, а массив инстансов `FormGroup`:

```
userData.contacts = [{
    contact_type: "phone",
    value: "380666666666"
}, {
    contact_type: "email",
    value: "ggg@gg.gg"
}, {
    contact_type: "website",
    value: "www.good.co"
}];

this.contactInfoForm = new FormGroup({
    contacts: this.fb.array([
        ...this.userData.contacts.map(({ contact_type, value }) => {
            return this.fb.group({
                contact_type,
                value
            });
        })
    ])
});
```

Не забываем про биндинг `formGroupName`:

```
<form [formGroup]="contactInfoForm" novalidate (submit)="submit('contactInfoForm')">
    <div formArrayName="contacts" *ngFor="let contact of contactInfoForm.get('contacts').controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i" <--- без квадратных скобок биндится буква `i`, как строка>
            <label>{{ contact.value.contact_type }}</label>
            <input formControlName="value">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: пока что работает. но мне не хотелось юзать мап или тому подобные методы. по стандарту же FormBuilder.array() должно нормально все делать. как то же люди выводят=) ща буду разбиратся что и как. а добавление нового контакта будет ок? там же тупо пуш?

Comment: вот тут https://medium.com/@maks.zhitlov/reactive-forms-in-angular-2f8abe884f79 норм вроде бы сделано. но я пытался. не работает) те же ошибки